# Why my external USB 3 drive has better 4K write speed than WD Black?

Tags: usb-3, speedtest

Please take a look at the image below. I’m wondering why my external USB 3 2.5 drive has 4K speed write much faster than my internal WD Black 3.5 drive?

[image: Speed Test]

Comment: Probably because the surface is a lot smaller.

Comment: I have many WD My Passport 2.5 drives and they are not this good. Their 4K write speed is around 0.5, the same like the read speed.

Comment: The 4K write speed for the external drive is nearly the same without and with a Queue dept of 32. I suspect that there is some different caching going on here where internal and external drive are acting differently. To get a proper comparision omunt both drives internall or both externally.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have many other Western Digital USB 3 external 2.5" drives. Non are this good. I'm very surprised by this speed with Transcend. It means this external drive is performing better than my internal which is troubling to me. Are there any other software I can use to test further?